# How to bind two nested structures using pybind11

Tags: pybind11

```cpp
typedef struct _Names
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Names;

typedef struct _values
{
    Names names;
}values;
```

binding code I have is

```cpp
py::class_<Names>(m, "Names")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("a", &Names::a)
    .def_readwrite("b", &Names::b)     
    .def_readwrite("c", &Names::c);

py::class_<values>(m, "values")
    .def(py::init<>()) 
    .def_readwrite("names", &values::names);
```

but I am unable to access names.a or names.b or names.c.

How can I bind names with Names structure?

Answer (score 4):

welcome to SO!

Hum, it should work. My guess is that your python code doesn't instantiate the class `values` correctly.

I have

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py=pybind11;

typedef struct _Names
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Names;

typedef struct _values
{
    Names names;
} values;


// Wrapping code
PYBIND11_MODULE(wrapper, m) {
    py::class_<Names>(m, "Names")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &Names::a)
        .def_readwrite("b", &Names::b)
        .def_readwrite("c", &Names::c);

    py::class_<values>(m, "values")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("names", &values::names);
}
```

And if I compile it (see [example 1 in this github repo](https://github.com/cjaques/pybind_examples) if you need directions) to a file called `wrapper`, I can use it from python as

```py
import wrapper

b = wrapper.values()  # <-- don't forget the parenthesis !
b.names.a = 30
print(b.names.a)  # prints 30
```

I'm guessing you didn't put parenthesis after `wrapper.values` which causes (in my case) `b` to contain the class definition instead of an instance of it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: you're welcome! Please, [mark the question as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .  Cheers